# Impute Missing Correlations from Incomplete Correlation Matrix in R

Tags: r, correlation, maximum-likelihood, data-imputation, determinant

I am in need of a function that will take an incomplete correlation matrix and return a complete matrix with correlations imputed for missing values. I am working on models that utilize only summary statistics from studies, so there's no access to raw data at all and no way of pooling correlation matrices from multiple places. Additionally, the missingness in the correlation matrix needs to be in potentially any cells.

For context, the model that I am working with is a finite mixture model for assigning an observed vector of scores to one of an arbitrary number of multivariate normal populations. The model defines the multivariate normal populations using summary statistics (means, standard deviations, and correlation matrices) reported in studies, normative manuals, etc. I know from simulation studies that the model works very well when all this information is known. Realistically, a complete correlation matrix between all the tests that a user might be interested in is likely rare as this information is more infrequently reported in research studies. As a result, the most likely scenario that a user of my model may encounter is that they are able to piece together most of the correlation matrix but still have some lingering unknown intercorrelations between tests (it is much less likely that the missing data come from means and standard deviations not being reported for a particular reference sample). For example, consider the incomplete correlation matrix below:

```
cor.mat <- matrix(c(1.00, 0.49,  NA , 0.46,
                    0.49, 1.00,  NA , 0.54,
                     NA ,  NA , 1.00, 0.53,
                    0.46, 0.54, 0.53, 1.00),
                     nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
```

There's nothing particularly remarkable about this correlation matrix, so this is really just an exemplar of the kind of problem that might need to be addressed. My understanding of how to maximize the determinant of this correlation matrix would be to invert it, replace the NA cells with 0, and then invert the matrix back. In R, trying `solve(cor.mat)` as is will produce a matrix of NAs, and I'm not familiar enough with matrix algebra in R to know how to get around that.

There are a couple papers on the problem that I have found useful, but they are both beyond my technical knowledge with respect for how to implement them in R. [This paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cl2.1068) mentions an R package that seemingly is no longer available, though if anyone knows where to find the original source code then that would be very helpful. [This paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsos.172348#FN2R) recommends imputation using the maximum determinant of the correlation matrix, and I have seen this offered as a solution before; however, I don't know how to write an `optim` statement for the determinant, particularly in a correlation matrix with an arbitrary number of missing correlations.

Are there other implementations for this problem out there? I assumed this was something that would come up in meta-analysis literature, though I have found that literature relatively unhelpful so far. If not, then can anyone help shed light on how to set up this problem in an R function?

Relatedly, I have seen that it is possible to place boundaries on what the missing correlations could be. I must assume that the correlation matrix is positive definite because my model takes the Cholesky decomposition of the supplied correlation matrix. The boundaries are potentially of interest to me, but what would be more meaningful is knowing the kind of distribution we might place over correlations within that boundary. I assume that this is not a uniform distribution where any correlation between those boundaries is equally likely with respect to probability, but I don't know whether that is accurate when there is not additional information that can inform what the missing correlations are. In my field, it is well known that tests tend to correlate with one another (r = 0.30-0.40 is fairly common), so assuming correlations near 0 or 1 is highly unlikely and hence why I'd prefer to not assume a uniform distribution there (though my preference and what is mathematically appropriate are obviously not always aligned with one another).

Comment: This is not one problem but many: the solution depends on *why* the entries are missing and how you intend to use the imputed correlation matrix.  What is your specific situation?

Comment: @whuber - I'll edit the comment to add more context. Essentially, I have a model that, assuming multivariate normality, attempts to assign a vector of observed test scores to one of several competing populations. The competing populations are based on summary statistics defining the multivariate normal distribution (sample means, standard deviations, and correlation matrix). It is rare that means and standard deviations are not reported, but in my field and with these tests, a full correlation matrix is rare, though pieces of the matrix are likely reported across various studies/publications